# Count number of ones in an array of bits

Tags: system-verilog

I want to count the number of ones in a packed array. I came up with the following code:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Va6

I think it can be done easier. Any suggestion?

```
 typedef bit bit6_t[5:0];

 module test_rand;
     bit [5:0] mask_packed;
     bit mask_packed_bit[5:0];
     int mask_unpacked[5:0];
     initial begin
       mask_packed = $urandom_range(((2**6)-1),0);
       mask_packed_bit = bit6_t'(mask_packed);
       foreach (mask_packed_bit[i]) begin mask_unpacked[i] = int'(mask_packed_bit[i]); end
       $display("*********************************");
       $display("mask_packed   = %p",mask_packed);
       $display("mask_unpacked     = %p",mask_unpacked);
       $display("mask_unpacked.sum = %p",mask_unpacked.sum());
       $display("*********************************");
     end
 endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
typedef bit bit6_t[5:0];

module test_rand;
    bit [5:0] mask_packed;
    bit6_t mask_unpacked;
    initial begin
      mask_packed   = $urandom_range(((2**6)-1),0);
      mask_unpacked = bit6_t'(mask_packed);
      $display("*********************************");
      $display("mask_packed   = %p",mask_packed);
      $display("mask_unpacked   = %p",mask_unpacked);
      $display("mask_unpacked.sum = %p",mask_unpacked.sum() with (int'(item)));
      $display("*********************************");
    end
endmodule
```

Working example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5cXx

Answer (score 3):

1) For plain verilog code:

Your last implicit $cast to 'int is unnecessary. Since you only want the sum, you can:

```
typedef bit bit6_t[5:0];

module test_rand;
    bit [5:0] mask_packed;
    bit mask_packed_bit[5:0];
    int sum = 0;
    initial begin
      mask_packed = $urandom_range(((2**6)-1),0);
      mask_packed_bit = bit6_t'(mask_packed);
      foreach (mask_packed_bit[i]) begin sum += mask_packed_bit[i]; end
      $display("*********************************");
      $display("mask_packed   = %p",mask_packed);
      $display("mask_packed_bit   = %p",mask_packed_bit);
      $display("sum = %p",sum);
      $display("*********************************");
    end
endmodule
```

Working example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5ZTW

2) If you are using systemverilog, you can use the simple **$countones** function.

```
module test_rand;
    bit [5:0] mask_packed;
    initial begin
      mask_packed = $urandom_range(((2**6)-1),0);
      $display("*********************************");
      $display("mask_packed   = %p",mask_packed);
      $display("countones = %p", $countones(mask_packed));
      $display("*********************************");
    end
endmodule
```

Working example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Nsd